# Java: Generator a random value then add 1 to the value in another variable

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, random

I know smilar questions have been asked about this, however non of the ones i have seen so far seems to help me in the way i need it to.

I want to be able to add 1 to the random value i get.

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.nextInt( 200);

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Level").orderByKey()
                    .startAt(String.valueOf(rand)).endAt(String.valueOf(rand));
```

the `endAt` need to be +1 of the rand value

if i do `rand +1` I get the error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to Java.Random

Anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: Can you show us how you initialize the `Random`? What does `String.valueOf(rand)` create? Isn't that a `toString()`-like representation of the instance `rand`? Why don't you do anything like a real random `int`, e.g.`String.valueOf(rand.nextInt() + 1)`?

Comment: `Random` is not a number, it's a generator. You need to call `nextInt()` to make it generate a number. So: `String.valueOf(rand.nextInt())` and `String.valueOf(rand.nextInt() + 1)`.

Comment: ```Random rand = new Random();```
        ```rand.nextInt( 200);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, it helped me figure out what i did wrong:

**My Answer:**

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int x = rand.nextInt(200);

    startAt(String.valueOf(x)).endAt(String.valueOf(x++));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                              .getReference("Level")
                              .orderByKey()
                              .startAt(String.valueOf(rand))
                              .endAt(String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(200)+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities to achieve this:

You could do `startAt(rand++)` or `endAt(++rand)`

Or `rand+=1`

Or you make a variable for just holding the correct value for endAt

```
int randStart = random(); 
int randEnd = randstart+1;
```

Comment: it is not allowing me to do the addition operator or any normal operation on the random value